# why initstate_r crashes when using variables on the stack

Tags: c++, linux, gnu

**Sorry this question not end yet.**

I'm trying to write a thread-safe random generator, but 
it crashes at

```
initstate_r(time(NULL), m_state_buff, sizeof(m_state_buff), &m_data);
```

My gcc version:
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

class RandomGenerator
{
public:
    RandomGenerator()
    {
        initstate_r(time(NULL), m_state_buff, sizeof(m_state_buff), &m_data);
    }

    virtual ~RandomGenerator() {}

public:
    int32_t get_next_int()
    {
#ifdef __GNUC__
        static __thread char stat_buff[512];
        static __thread random_data buff;
        static __thread bool inited = false;

        if (!inited)
        {
               initstate_r(time(NULL), stat_buff, sizeof(stat_buff), &buff);
               srandom_r(time(NULL), &buff);
               inited = true;
        }

        int32_t result = 0;

        random_r(&buff, &result);
        return result;
#endif
    }

private:
    struct random_data m_data;
    char m_state_buff[512];
};


int main()
{
    RandomGenerator r;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", r.get_next_int());
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to provide some self containing testcase that people can copy, paste, compile and run for themselves.

Comment: Hm, have you read in the manpage about the initstate_r function?

Comment: you mean, I need call initstat_r first, then call srandom_r()?

Comment: I never use those random functions, but the manpage reads like you do.

Comment: Please see the CPP test code.

Comment: Can't reproduce, the above compiles and runs here (GCC 4.5.4, 4.6.3, 4.7.2).

Comment: I believe this related to the libc initstate_r() 's bug. An initialization method should not re-use the buffer's value, it should clean it first.

When I cleanup the buffer before call initstate_r() the segmentation fault has gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this related to the libc initstate_r() 's bug.
An initialization method should not re-use the buffer's value, it should clean it first.

When I cleanup the buffer before call initstate_r() the segmentation fault has gone.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

class RandomGenerator
{
public:
    RandomGenerator()
    {
        memset(m_state_buff, 0, sizeof(m_state_buff));
        memset(&m_data, 0, sizeof(m_data);
        initstate_r(time(NULL), m_state_buff, sizeof(m_state_buff), &m_data);
    }

    virtual ~RandomGenerator() {}

private:
    struct random_data m_data;
    char m_state_buff[512];
};


int main()
{
    RandomGenerator r;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", r.get_next_int());
    }
}
```